# planning the GUI before starting to program

Tags: user-interface

Does anybody know if there's a free aplication which I can use to plan my application GUI?
I'd like to draw it (like in paint), before I start programming it.
thanks :)

Comment: what platform to you use (windows/linux/OSX/other?) what language/dev environment are you targeting (some have stuff builtin directly)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best web app for creating screen mockups?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528769/best-web-app-for-creating-screen-mockups)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of options. I usually use paper and a pencil, then WPF (typing XAML gets me pretty far fairly quickly, when only needing standard controls) and then actually implement it (which was in Swing the last time, hence the WPF prototype which took only an hour, not a week).

There is the [Powerpoint Prototyping toolkit](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20071018/powerpoint-prototype-toolkit-01/) which lets you create prototypes, even halfway functional ones, easily.

Comment: @Idov: If you have clients to satisfy be *very* cautious about making it pretty. If it looks like it's already complete then they *expect it to be complete already*. There's a reason that most mockups clearly communicate with their sketchy form that they are mockups and not yet a finished product. However, the Powerpoint one looks fairly nice, already.

Answer (score 4):

Paper. It's simple, cheap, easy to modify, full-compatible with all toolkits and doesn't have a long learning curve.

Comment: Where can I download it from? :P

Answer (score 0):

Use netbean's UI designer and capture the screen.